# get inet, bcast and mask from ifconfig

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to get any and all inet, bcast and mask IPs from the ifconfig command in java.  But am struggling to get the regex right.

Here is my naive attempt:  And I have tried several variations of using "\s" and "  " for the spaces.

```
String string;
try {
    // discover ip addresses
    writer.write("Discovering available network connections...\n\n");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    // String ifconfigCmd = "/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }'";
    String ifconfigCmd = "ifconfig";
    System.out.println("executing `" + ifconfigCmd + "`");

    Process ifconfigProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ifconfigCmd);
    BufferedReader ifconfigProcReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ifconfigProc.getInputStream()));

    // read output of ifconfig command
    HashSet<String> subnets = new HashSet<>();
    String ipaddress, inet, bcast, mask;
    String ipaddressPattern = "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                               "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                               "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                               "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
    while ((ipaddress = ifconfigProcReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("ifconfig       : " + ipaddress);

        String pStr = ".*(inet addr:(?<inet>" + ipaddressPattern + "))?.*(Bcast:(?<bcast>" + ipaddressPattern + "))?.*(Mask:(?<mask>" + ipaddressPattern + "))?.*";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pStr).matcher(ipaddress);
        if (m.matches()) {
            try {
                inet = m.group("inet");
                System.out.println("inet           : " + inet);
                if (inet != null) {
                    int i = inet.lastIndexOf(".");
                    System.out.println("last index of .: " + i);
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        ipaddress = ipaddress.substring(0, i+1) + "*";
                        System.out.println("subnet         : " + ipaddress);
                        subnets.add(ipaddress);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {}

            try {
                bcast = m.group("bcast");
                System.out.println("bcast          : " + bcast);
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {}

            try {
                mask = m.group("mask");
                System.out.println("mask           : " + mask);
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Is anyone able to help out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way I would do it:

```
    ....
    inet = null;
    bcast = null;
    mask = null;
    ....
    while ((ipaddress = ifconfigProcReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inet != null && bcast != null && mask != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (inet == null)
            {
                inet = search("inet addr:[0-9.]+", ipaddress, "inet addr:");
            }
            if (bcast == null)
            {
                bcast = search("Bcast:[0-9.]+", ipaddress, "Bcast:");
            }
            if (mask == null)
            {
                mask = search("Mask:[0-9.]+", ipaddress, "Mask:");
            }
        }
    //check if you have got all the ip address populated
    // in inet, bcast, mask
    ....
    ....


        private String search(String regex, String line, String removeString)
        {
            Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(line);
            String ipAddress = null;
            if (matcher.find())
            {
                ipAddress = matcher.group().replaceFirst(removeString, "");
            }
            return ipAddress;
        }
```

You can also use regex like so:

```
....
regex = "(inet addr:)([0-9.]+)";
.....

if(matcher.find()){
    ipAddress = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like how it breaks up the regex into smaller pieces too.  Much easier to read and understand.  Thanks!